# jQuery slide functions acting up in google chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am currently developing a new site for the Agency I work for which can be found here:

http://www.astwood.co.uk/testsite/wordpress/

At the top-right there are two buttons that slide down extra content for the contact and about us sections. I have animated the appearance of the extra divs using the following jQuery:

Hides the content on the page on load:

```
$("#about").hide();
$("#contact").hide();
```

Shows and hides the content when a link with the specified class is clicked:

```
$(".aboutbtn").click(function () {
   $('#contact').slideUp(
   function() {

        $('#about').slideToggle('slow');

   });
});

$(".contactbtn").click(function () {
   $('#about').slideUp(
   function() {

        $('#contact').slideToggle('slow');

   });
});
```

This works perfectly in most browsers, it will hide the existing open div if there is one and then open the specified section. However, in chrome for mac, the first time a button is pressed after page load it will slide down the content requested and immediately slide it back up again.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce it on Chrome (23.something) for Mac, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: No problems with Chrome 23.0.1271 on OS X 10.8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out it was a browser plugin that was interfering with how the jQuery should have been working. The browser extension in question was Double Click which can be found here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/double-click/mdoabndnbhmbbiggngmjbnoijnhfophe

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that the `$("#about").hide();` and `$("#contact").hide();` are being run late in the chrome browser (seems to work ok with chrome on my PC...).

Try putting a css style of `display:none` on the elements, as opposed to using jQuery to hide them. This means when the browser renders them (before the javascript even runs) they will be hidden.

Comment: That wouldn't explain why the element slides down and then up again immediately. If it was the .hide(); function that was doing it it would just disappear. And yeah im pretty sure its a Mac - Chrome thing as it works on my windows pc, and all other browsers on mac.

Comment: Try replacing the `slideToggle` with a `slideDown` just to see if it's a problem with the toggle...

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas :

- orchestrate the toggle action yourself rather that rely on `.slideToggle()`;
- issue `.stop(true,true)` on the requested element prior to sliding it up/down

One or other or both of these together *may* have the right effect, though it's hard to know why.

Here's the code for both ideas together :

```
$(".aboutbtn").click(function() {
    var $about = $("#about").stop(true,true);
    $("#contact").slideUp(function() {
        var fn = ($about.is(":hidden")) ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp';
        $about[fn]('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Totally weird. What happens if you perform the initial hides with `.slideUp()` instead of `.hide()`?

Comment: Has the same problem. Starting to think its a problem with Chrome more than the code.

Comment: I just tried deactivating the plugins on chrome and it seems to be working fine now... Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Just add clear: both to the div/container to whom you are applying slideToggle()

Overflow hidden is required for the animation, and it is not able to get the height properly.

It worked out for me with clear:both.